# FK mismatch sqlite

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite3, chave-estrangeira

Boa tarde
Tenho um erro de FK mismatch no SQLite que já está me perturbando mas não consigo ver o problema, segue o esqueleto do banco:

```
CREATE TABLE CEST_Item (
  CIT_ID integer primary key
, CIT_COD numeric(4,1)
, CIT_Nome varchar
);

CREATE TABLE CEST_Segmento (
  CSE_ID integer primary key
, CSE_COD varchar(3)
, CSE_Nome varchar
);

CREATE TABLE SistemaUnidade (
  UNI_ID integer primary key
, UNI_UN varchar(20)
, UNI_Descricao varchar
);

CREATE TABLE NCM (
  NCM_ID integer primary key
, NCM_COD varchar(10)
, NCM_Categoria varchar
, NCM_Descricao varchar
, NCM_IPI varchar(2)
, NCM_DataInicio Date
, NCM_Datafim Date
, UNI_ID integer
, NCM_GTINP Date
, NCM_GTINH Date
, NCM_OBS varchar
, foreign key(UNI_ID) references SistemaUnidade(UNI_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CEST (
  CEST_ID integer primary key
, CEST_COD varchar(9)
, NCM_COD varchar(10)
, CSE_COD varchar(3)
, CIT_ID integer
, CEST_Anexo varchar
, foreign key(NCM_COD) references NCM(NCM_COD)
, foreign key(CSE_COD) references CEST_Segmento(CSE_COD)
, foreign key(CIT_ID) references CEST_Item(CIT_ID)
);
```

Ao inserir dados nas tabelas acessórias tudo acontece normalmente sem problema algum, porém quando vou tentar fazer o seguinte insert dá o erro de FK mismatch:
`INSERT INTO CEST VALUES(NULL, '01.001.00', '3815.12.10', '01', (SELECT CIT_ID FROM CEST_ITEM WHERE CIT_Nome like 'Catalisadores em colmeia cerâmica ou metálica para conversão catalítica de gases de escape de veículos e outros catalisadores'), '');`

Sim, as tabelas possuem valores:

```
INSERT INTO CEST_Segmento VALUES(NULL, '01', 'Autopeças');
INSERT INTO CEST_Item VALUES(NULL, 1.0, 'Catalisadores em colmeia cerâmica ou metálica para conversão catalítica de gases de escape de veículos e outros catalisadores');
INSERT INTO NCM VALUES(NULL, '3815.12.10', 'PLÁSTICO E SUAS OBRAS', '3909.40.91 - FENOL-FORMALDEÍDO', '5', '42370', '', 4, '08/04/2019', '01/11/2018', '');
```

Se eu trocar a subquery por um valor fixo ocorre o mesmo problema, essa aqui é a mensagem de erro:

```
foreign key mismatch - "CEST" referencing "CEST_Segmento"

SQL Statement:

-- CEST
-- ID | COD | NCM | CODSEG | IDITEM | Anexo
INSERT INTO CEST VALUES(NULL, '01.001.00', '3815.12.10', '01', (SELECT CIT_ID FROM CEST_ITEM WHERE CIT_Nome like 'Catalisadores em colmeia cerâmica ou metálica para conversão catalítica de gases de escape de veículos e outros catalisadores'), '');.
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Note que `foreign key(NCM_COD) references NCM(NCM_COD)` e `foreign key(CSE_COD) references CEST_Segmento(CSE_COD)` não referenciam uma linha univocamente determinada nas tabelas destino.

Comment: @anonimo mas de acordo com o site do SQLite, a sintaxe tá correta: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html
```CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);```
O que eu teria que fazer diferente então?

Comment: A sintaxe está correta, o que está errado é que os campos referenciados nestas duas constraints não são chaves primárias ou chaves candidatas, o que é obrigatório em uma foreign key. Vide documentação: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html